# How to trigger a callback function when we receive notification from app server through fcm even when the app is Killed?

Tags: ionic4

How do i trigger the callback function onMesageReceived() in ionic 4 when app is killed?

Tried sending data message but not worked

```
var payload = {
      notification: {
        title: title,
        body: body,
      },

      data: {
        questionnaire_id: id,
        appointmentID: appointmentID,
        is_questionnaire: 'true',
        notification_foreground: 'true',
      },
};
```

This is how i am sending notification

I am expecting callback to be triggered when app is closed /Killed

Comment: Did you find a solution please?